# SQL Server does not perform job logic correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, service, logic

I have some maintenance job, here is structure:

[image]

Step 1 and 3 just checking where are

Step 1 and 3 just checking  where is specific database is currently resides - is it primary or secondary replica

```
If sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica ( 'DATABASENAME') <> 1   
   BEGIN  
           RAISERROR ('Not PRIMARY REPLICA FOR DATABASE NAME', -- Message text.  
           16, -- Severity.  
           1 -- State.  
           ); 
    END
```

STEP 2 and 4 just performs backup of specific database using Ola script

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'SOMEDB',
@Directory = 'SOMESHARE',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 336,
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y',
@Compress = 'Y'
```

Step 1 moves job execution to Step 3 in case of database is not on primary replica now

Step 3 quit with success in case of failure

This works well on secondary replica and job quit with success with failed first and third step

But on primary replica there absolutely strange things happening and SQL agent can mix step or doing logic that should not happen anyway. Looks like following

[image]

Comment: If secondary replica job is correct, drop it from the primary, script it from the secondary and recreate it on the primary.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebooted the  server and now everything working fine , its probably happened because of installing multiple windows and sql server patches since last 5 days without reboot whole server.